# Is it possible run OWS (orange file) in pyhton script or convert it do .py

Tags: python, machine-learning, orange

I would like to run Orange files in a Python script.

I'm testing a machine learning dev process, and I found the Orange Data Mining (https://orange.biolab.si/).

It's a visual IDE that I can create a machine learning. But I would like to convert Orange file generated in OWS to a .py script or call this file from a .py script.

Could you help me?

Comment: There's a long discussion about this here: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/1341

In short - no you can't.